# Installing fonts in LibreOffice

Tags: raspbian

Is there an easy way to install multiple fonts in LibreOffice? I am a relative newcomer to the Raspberry PI. I am using a Raspberry Pi 4b with Raspbian installed. I know some basic commands (sudo, apt-get etc.) So far I am basically ignorant when it come to file handling using the terminal window. I am quite proficient using file manager though. Please help if you can.

Comment: Are they listed here: https://packages.debian.org/stable/fonts/? -> with apt-get. Or if you have the .ttf file, something like this: https://vitux.com/how-to-install-custom-fonts-on-a-debian-10-system/
You are not confined to Raspbian. Google for Debian/Ubuntu solutions, Raspbian is a derivative

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have managed to install the font manager and, install two fonts.You have uncrossed my eyes and now, my hair can start to grow back!  I'm not sure how easy that would be for someone that has never dealt with similar problems before but thankfully I, found it pretty straightforward. Can I do anything to up your reputation score or, is that automatic now that my question is answered?

Comment: I made an answer. Click on the `accept answer` to mark this solved and maybe upvote if it's a good answer.

Comment: If you like the MS fonts there is a way of installing them without having to rip them out of Office - documented https://itsfoss.com/install-microsoft-fonts-ubuntu/

Comment: The question really does not belong to Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I'm sorry if I posted this in the wrong place.  At the time of posting I was under the impression that the fonts had to be installed  as system fonts and that, they would be specific to the Raspberry.  Being relatively new user of the Raspberry and, this forum I, posted it here. Swedgin has answered my question very fully and been extremely helpful.  Your comment of it not belonging here is very brief.  Could you please tell me where it should be posted and, do you yourself have any suggestion as to how to solve the problem that may differ from the advice given by Swedgin?

Comment: Thank you Andyroo. I took the advice from Swedgin and now have lots of great fonts for my projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this.

1. by using `apt-get` like you would install any other package if the font you want is listed in https://packages.debian.org/stable/fonts/
2. Install `font-manager` and download the `.ttf` font file from the internet. Open `font-manager` and click on the `+` button to add your downloaded font. (taken from https://vitux.com/how-to-install-custom-fonts-on-a-debian-10-system/)

Don't limit your google searches to Raspbian. Since it's a derivative of Debian, solutions for Debian/Ubuntu will also work.

Comment: Thank you for your help and, great suggestions.  Voted you up but due to my low level it doesn't show in the post but, apparently is recorded.  I also ticked to say that yours was the best answer, hope this helps you and, once again, thank you for all your help it, is most appreciated.

Comment: @ChrisSeymour All is good, no worries.